# How do I use CKSubscription in an iOS 10 messages extension?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ios10, ios-messages-extension

iOS 10 introduced messages extensions, which are the first (to my knowledge) extension which does not require a host application. I am trying to use CloudKit in a messages extension which does not have a host app.

From what I can tell, `CKSubscription` relies on push notifications. However, I cannot register for push notifications in the usual way (via `UIApplication`) in app extensions:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared // Error: not available here blah blah blah
```

This means it is seemingly impossible to receive `CKSubscription` notifications in a messages app. I did find hope in the new `UserNotifications.framework`, but it does not provide any mechanisms for registering for remote notifications. I tried:

```
override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {

    // ...

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert]) { success, error in
        if error != nil { fatalError() }
    }
    center.delegate = self

    // ...
}

// MARK: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    fatalError() // This never gets called :(
}
```

But when I update records that are the subject of my `CKSubscription`, no notification is presented to the user and the delegate is not notified.

Here's my `CKSubscription` code:

```
let sub = CKRecordZoneSubscription(zoneID: legitimateZone)

let notifInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notifInfo.alertBody = "Wow it works! Amazing!"
sub.notificationInfo = notifInfo

privateDB.save(sub) { sub, error in
    if let e = error {
        fatalError("Error saving zone sub: \(e)")
    }
    print("Saved subscription")
}
```

How do I get `CKSubscription` notifications in a messages extension?

---

I don't even need the notification presented to the user, nor do I need to receive them in the background. All I want is to know when records are updated while my extension is running.

If there is another way to do this other than `CKSubscription` I'd love to hear as well (as long as it's not going to poll CloudKit constantly, wasting my precious 40 requests/sec).

I have tried on both a physical device and in the simulator.

Comment: Hey! I am struggling basically with the same thing. Do you already have a solution by any chance?

Comment: @Gustl007 No, I'm afraid I don't have a good solution. At this point I'm ensuring all record changes are the result of a message being sent. That way, whenever I receive a message while the extension is running, I know I should go and check for changes.

Comment: I did file a bug report for this also (rdar://problem/27731630)